# SAML Sample Identity Provider Certificate and Java Application for signing certificate

Tags: java, saml-2.0, opensaml

I have a Java web application. And I want to implement SAML SSO login for my application.
What I am trying to do is,

1. Need one sample identity provider certificate
2. Create a separate JSP application which will sign certificate and create assertion for my app.
3. Upload the public key of the certificate and save in keystore.
4. Whenever a user tries to login, the assertion from JSP application will be created and send to my web app.
5. Validate the public key with the key in keystore and proceed further.

Please correct me if I am wrong in this.

Also where can I find a sample identity provider certificate? Or may be how to create one?
Also is there any sample JSP application that can create assertion and send to my application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get free account at PingOne from [Ping Identity](https://www.pingidentity.com/en/get-started-with-ping.html).

After that you will be provided with certificate and meta information to use PingOne as identity provider.

Also you can try [TestShib](https://www.testshib.org/) or [OpenIdP](https://openidp.feide.no/).

You can use `keytool` command to manage certificates at your local system.

If you use JBoss AS/Wildfly then I suggest using Picketlink, you can find documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/PLINK/SAML+v2.0).

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Is there any other service link Ping. I am not able to register there. :)

Comment: You can try also [TestShib](https://www.testshib.org/) or [OpenIdP](https://openidp.feide.no/).

Comment: @iProgrammer Definitely check Picketlink, worked very well for me. And check the PicketLink docs, they have examples for SalesForce integration, both IdP as well as SP, it's good to play with.